# Packaging dependencies imported into a Node worker thread written in TypeScript, with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, node-worker-threads

We have a NodeJS worker thread written in TypeScript. The worker thread imports a third-party package (`fluent-ffmpeg`, though I don't think that specific package is the problem here) and uses said package to perform its work.

Everything works very well in development, yet when packaged with webpack 5.73.0 the third-party package (`fluent-ffmpeg`), which is imported into the worker thread script, `video_writer_worker.ts` by,

```
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
```

causes a runtime error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'fluent-ffmpeg'
Require stack:
- /Applications/Our.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/main/7c070378743d92c29276.ts
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:785:27)
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Our.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/main/7c070378743d92c29276.ts:29:41)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1118:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
```

The worker thread is initiated by from the main thread by,

```
this._worker = new Worker(
  new URL('./video_writer_worker.ts', import.meta.url),
  {
    workerData: { niceness, fps, savePath },
  }
);
```

How can we import dependencies into our node worker thread such that it can be packaged by webpack?